# Do high powered lasers refract differently than other light?

Tags: optics, water, laser, refraction

So I have a question: I am told that there are naval lasers that target over 100's of miles ship-to-ship (not ship to air). Someone asserted that powerful lasers would refract differently than light. If I am seeing something in the distance (due to refraction) could I fire a laser at it reliably?

Would the light coming from an object seen over the horizon provide a 'path' for a high powered laser to travel back to it?

Comment: A beam from a powerful laser is an intense beam of light. So no, not differently than light. Perhaps you are thinking of differently than a less intense laser? High power can cause heating that can cause distortion. Or perhaps differently than a laser beam that travels only a short distance? Light is absorbed and bent by the atmosphere over long distances.

Comment: A ship on the surface can't see another ship 100 miles away. Trying to hit it with a laser would not work.

Comment: can over the horizon refraction allow a laser weapon to hit something that would be optically visible?

Answer (score 4):

Lasers are light, so they refract the same as light. However, when light is travelling in a medium it might affect the medium. There are so-called non-linear self-lensing affects where the presence of high powered light changes the index of the refraction of the medium through which it is travelling, typically through, e.g. thermal effects.

Non-linear affects like these mean that the light will behave differently depending on its intensity.

I would be surprised if such lensing effects were non-negligible for ship-to-ship communication through air via lasers, but I have no experience with systems like that, so I don't know what kind of powers/intensities we're talking about, how indices of refraction and beam paths would be effected, etc.